# R shinydashboard: display progress bar while loading data (fread)

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I'm creating a R shinydashboard with a big database that takes a while to load.
Is it possible to create a progress bar that displays the information of the amount of data that has been read? (e.g., "Read X% of Z rows")?

Comment: [something like this](http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/progress.html) ?

Comment: I don't think so, because all of this involves some kind of control of the task that is being perfomed (e.g., a loop that contains some calculation). In this case I only have
dt <- fread("dt.csv", sep=";",header=T, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
and it takes 2 minutes. It would be great if i could display the fread progress as a progress bar. But thanks

Comment: Please share if you managed to get a solution for this!

Comment: I am looking for a solution to this exact problem. Any news on a solution yet?

Answer (score 0):

R cannot tell you how many rows are in your data until the initial load is complete (I think).  However, you can use the built in Shiny progress bar to give your users a message that the data is loading:

```
x<-list.files()

data<-data.frame()

withProgress(message = 'Reading Data!', value = 0, {

    for(i in 1:length(x)){
        incProgress(1/length(x), detail = paste("File #", i))
        hold<-read.csv(x[i])
        data<-rbind(data,hold)
    }
})
```

You can just replace the `read.csv()` with whatever command you are using (i.e. `fread("dt.csv", sep=";",header=T, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)`) to load data.  You could also intentionally do more than one big query to inform the progress bar in the loop.  If you are loading just one file change the message to something more appropriate (and the loop will only do one cycle, obviously).

Comment: This involves reading in multiple files and showing read in 1 of n files, however, the OP was looking for a solution that shows the loading of a single file. `fread` has a built in (console) loading status but it would be nice to find a solution that displays this in shiny.