# Shiny progress bar during loading RData, Package?

Tags: r, shiny

I am not sure if I can show any reproducible example here, however let me narrate the issue I am facing with my Shiny app.

I have a `Shiny` app, which is basically data driven. All my required data is saved in an `RData` file which is placed in `WWW` folder. When user put my Shiny app's address (which is hosted on `Amazon AWS`) i.e. when my `Shiny app` starts, that `RData` file is loaded onto R, and then subsequent calculation starts.

The issue is that, my `RData` file is of quite huge size `~50MB`. So R takes quite long time to load that onto memory. From User's perspective, he/she is not sure what is happening behind the screen, that makes some of them leave my App.

So I was thinking if I can put some progress bar to show User something is happening, as that Progress bar would be displayed only during the time when R is loading my `RData` file. I am aware of various Progress bar schemes available for Shiny, however as far as I know they are to display progress only during calculation (e.g. simulation) not during loading something.

Any idea if it is possible to put some Progress bar during loading `RData`, `package` etc?

Thanks for any pointer.

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31397741/r-shinydashboard-display-progress-bar-while-loading-data-fread

Comment: Hi DJack - the link is helpful. However, it implements server-side loading of data. Server-side loading of Packages also can be done with this approach. But how can a similar thing be done for UI side loading of package/data? Sometimes loading of package takes considerable amount of time

Comment: I am looking for an answer to this same question, except I am using `fread` (which has a built-in loading bar that prints to the console). Any news on a solution to this yet?

Answer (score 1):

maybe a bit late but I share what I used, should it be useful for someone else.

Take a look at the `shinycssloaders` package (https://github.com/andrewsali/shinycssloaders).

By adding a simple function `withSpinner` and set a few parameters, you'll be able to set loader animations to Shiny apps. Furthermore you can select different spinners by looking at this link https://projects.lukehaas.me/css-loaders/.

I used it when I made this app: https://abenedetti.shinyapps.io/bioNPS/
Look at the *Species Choropleth map* section.

Edit:
Maybe this [article](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/progress.html) and this [app](https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/progress-bar-example.html) could help. Did you had a look at them?

Comment: Thanks for sharing this information. While this is useful to display that App is still working on, however I wanted to have something to display how much work is still remaining (like %) - this information will not be available with this.