# Capture data loading from fread into a shiny withProgress bar in R

Tags: r, shiny, progress-bar, fread

I am loading in a **large** data file using `fread` which is from: `library(data.table)`. `fread` by default shows the status of how long it is taking to read in the file but it *only prints to the console*.

I would like to capture the loading time of data and display it in real time in the shiny application so the user understands why there is a delay and roughly how long the data read is taking. I would like to use `withProgress` since this produces a loading bar and you can display text defining what the program is doing.

Typically, `withProgress` is incremented by a numeric scale using `incProgress`, however, I am looking for a way to do something like this:

```
withProgress(message = 'Loading Data', {
        d <- fread("file_name.csv") # Pick a random (large) file to load
})
```

The problem with the above code is that the load bar isn't being incremented (I don't think that `withProgress` detects the loading by `fread` automatically). The load bar shows up and only increments a small amount but it is not correctly capturing the loading time from `fread`.

**Update**
I was able to find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31397741/r-shinydashboard-display-progress-bar-while-loading-data-fread) similar question, however, the only answer given to this question uses the loading bar to indicate the progress of loading many files (`Loaded 2 of n files`). My problem is trying to show the progression of reading in a single large file.
I know `fread` knows how many rows a file contains after the initial scan because in the console it does show the progress. I just need to know how to tap into that to use it in the progress bar.

Here is an example of how `fread` displays the read in progress:
[image: fread progress]

**fread Documentation**
If you look up the documentation for `fread` this is what it says about the built in `showProgess` option:

```
TRUE displays progress on the console using \r. 
It is produced in freads C code where the very nice (but R level)
txtProgressBar and tkProgressBar are not easily available.
showProgress = getOption("datatable.showProgress")  # default: TRUE
```